# Getting error when trying to add headers in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm fairly new to angular 2 and am trying to make an http request with headers.

I've been following a tutorial, that may be out of date, as I'm getting an error when trying to include Headers.

I'm importing the Headers module:

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

Here is my method, where I try to include the headers:

```
  memberInfo(){
    let headers = new Headers().set('Authorization', this.authToken);
    this.http.get(this.API_ENDPOINT + '/memberinfo', { headers });
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ headers: void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
```

Any insight would be great!!

Comment: Try changing `{ headers }` to `{ headers: headers }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
let header = new Headers();
header.append(´Authorization´, this.authToken);
this.http.get(this.API_ENDPOINT + ´/memberinfo´, {headers: header})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign to **`headers`**

```
 this.http.get(this.API_ENDPOINT + '/memberinfo', { headers: headers });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },{'Authorization'´: this.authToken});
this.http.get(this.API_ENDPOINT + ´/memberinfo´, {headers: header})
```

if you're expecting some response then:

```
this.http.get(this.API_ENDPOINT + ´/memberinfo´, {headers: header}).map(response => response.json());
```

Here I am converting GET request response and converting it to JSON.